# Need help in verifying a map to be monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

While studying algebra from Thomas Hungerford I have a question in proof of Theorem 7.11 on page 298.

It's image:

[image]

[image]

In last fifth line of proof I am not able to verify how the map $\sigma -> \bar {i} $ is an monomorphism.

How to prove that it's an homomorphism?
The operation on left is a coposition and operation on right is multiplication.

So, $\sigma_{2} \sigma_{1} (u) $ is lhs of inequality but how to obtain rhs of this equality from it.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^i$ then I write $\sigma=\sigma_i$. Thus
$$
\sigma_i(\sigma_j(\zeta))=\sigma_i(\zeta^j)=(\zeta^j)^i=\zeta^{ij}
$$
hence $\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_{ij}$. So we have a mapping
$$
\Phi:Aut_KF\to \mathbb{Z}_n
$$
with  $\Phi(\sigma_i)=\overline{i}$. Then
$$
\Phi(\sigma_i\sigma_j)=\Phi(\sigma_{ij})=\overline{ij}=\overline{i}\cdot \overline{j}
$$